# When should I use an Outlet and property, say for a button?

Tags: objective-c

I can never remember, when should I use an Outlet and property, say for a button?

Comment: You need to ask a much more specific question.

Comment: I'm basically asking whats the different between them and when should I use outlets and not properties. I can never remember.

Comment: It's two different things, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1) is a part of Objective-C language (automatic/manual generating of getter and setter for object instances of a particular class), [outlet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/ApplicationBasics/ApplicationBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005344-CH3-SW1) is a part of Cocoa API interface bulding (connecting NIB elements and object instances of a particular class). Write it on your sticky note :)